# How do you make a TOC link cover text and page number?

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents, links

The hyperref package allows you to specify that TOC links in the pdf cover the text (default) or the page number (linktocpage=true), but not both.  That is, you can have this:

```
 [My Title]. . . . . . . . . . . 15
```

Or this:

```
  My Title . . . . . . . . . . .[15]
```

But not this:

```
 [My Title . . . . . . . . . . . 15]
```

...where the brackets encompass the portion of the line that is a clickable link.

My question: how do you specify that you make the whole line a clickable link?  Is there a package that allows you to specify this?

Answer (score 22):

`linktoc=all`, as described in the hyperref README.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was looking at the hyperref documentation here, which does not document that command at all:

http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html

Comment: @John: if this answer solved your problem, it would be nice if you would mark it as accepted.