# link both page number and text in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Hyperref's `linktocpage` option will "*make page number, not text, be link on TOC, LOF and LOT*."  Is there a way to make both the page number **and** the text be a link?

Comment: Note, upon further inspection my question is a duplicate of this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/how-do-you-make-a-toc-link-cover-text-and-page-number

Comment: It would be great if someone could update the `hyperref` [documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) since after **2.5 years**, it's still out of date...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `linktoc=all` option for `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=cyan,linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]