# How to refine links in LOF entries (in memoir)?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir

I would like to abuse the LOF as a kind of bibliography for foreign figures. For that it would be very nice to change the linking of the LOF entries. The default links entry names to figures but hyperlinks introduced with `\href` override them. The problem is that they are indistinguishable without hovering over them with the mouse and so the hyperlinks do not stand out enough (at least with my formatting of links).

My conceived solution disables the links to the figures in the entry names and adds links to them in the page number blocks instead. Hyperlinks done with `\href` should still work normally in the entry names.

I have looked into memoir's definition of \l@figure but apparently I would need to do some voodoo with hyperref too? And I don't even know where to start...

Below is the promised MWE. In the generated .pdf "0.1 By AAuthor, from " should not be a link to the figure but the 1 at the end should be, and "ASource" should still link to http://example.com.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatother

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citebordercolor=0 0 0,
    filebordercolor=0 0 0,
    linkbordercolor=0 0 0,
    menubordercolor=0 0 0,
    urlbordercolor=0 0 0,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U /W 0.2}, % stroke, underline, width 0.2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
figure A
\caption[By AAuthor, from \href{http://example.com}{ASource}]{ACaption.}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\hypersetup{linktocpage=true}
\listoffigures
\hypersetup{linktocpage=false}` However you have to put the complete caption text inside `\href`: `\caption[\href{http://example.com}{By AAuthor, from ASource}]{ACaption.}`

Comment: too easy ;) thanks! please make this an answer. i don't understand the second half of your comment. it works exactly as i want without putting it completely inside `\href`.

Comment: this is kind of a dupe: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/how-do-you-make-a-toc-link-cover-text-and-page-number but that explains, why i could not find it in the manual...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hyperref` provides the option `linktocpage` which can either `true` or `false`. This option can be used inside `\hypersetup`.

> make page number, not text, be link on TOC, LOF and LOT

So you can use:

```
\hypersetup{linktocpage=true}
 \listoffigures 
\hypersetup{linktocpage=false}
```

Comment: or `\hypersetup{linktoc=page} \listoffigures \hypersetup{linktoc=section}`