# How to extend link from text and page number to dots in table of contents (lualatex)

Tags: hyperref, luatex, tocloft

I spread table of contents links from text to also page number using this setting:

```latex
\hypersetup{linktoc=all}
```

But it doesn't include dots (`\renewcommand{\cftdot}{or whatever this value is}`), meaning that I can't click on dots to make a link jump - only on text and page number. Is there a way to do this?

In other words, how to make "unhighlighted text" also clickable:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,linktoc=all}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftdot{unhighlighted text}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Example section}
\end{document}
```

[The question is about the result in the example under "But not this:"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7074/282382)

P.S. To answer why I need this: in word processor programs you can add link to almost anything, so I wanted to know how to get to the same level of flexibility in terms of where I can add links in my documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't like to large link area on a page. They are difficult if you read on a touch screen as you constantly jump by mistake to other places.

But if you want can add a link, e.g. (I used borders instead of color links to better show which area they cover):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktoc=all}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftdot{unhighlighted text}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}\hyper@linkend}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Example section}
\subsection{sub}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick answer! Could you include a command that reverts this setting, please? So that I could, for example, apply this setting (in my documentclass) and then put `\UndoExpandLinkToDotsepInTOC` in preamble of some document (that uses my documentclass).

Comment: well simply redefine \cftsecleader back to your first definition.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't read carefully (I assumed it was a different command). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to expand the answer (it may be helpful to others). To change this for subsection, the command to renew is `\cftsubsecleader` and `\cftsubsubsecleader` for subsubsection.